# Button sizes changing on user control when control is added to window

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls

Okay, so I created a user control for a keypad. It looks like this:

[image]

The code for this is:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Button Content="1"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnOne" />

        <Button Content="4"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnFour" />

        <Button Content="7"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnSeven" />

        <Button Content="0"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnZero" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Button Content="2"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnTwo" />

        <Button Content="5"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnFive" />

        <Button Content="8"
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnEight" />

        <Button Content="."
                Height="60"
                Width="60"
                Margin="8"
                Name="bttnDecimal" />
    </StackPanel>

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Del"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Margin="8"
                    Height="60"
                    Name="bttnDelete" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Button Content="3"
                    Height="60"
                    Width="60"
                    Margin="8"
                    Name="bttnThree" />

            <Button Content="6"
                    Height="60"
                    Width="60"
                    Margin="8"
                    Name="bttnSix" />

            <Button Content="9"
                    Height="60"
                    Width="60"
                    Margin="8"
                    Name="bttnNine" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Ent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Width="60"
                    Margin="8"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Height="Auto"
                    Name="bttnEnter" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Now, when I added the keypad to the window, the window changes the size of the buttons, like this:

[image]

The code for that is:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Label Content="New Item"
               Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}"
               FontStyle="Italic" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Label Content="BHA Description"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
               FontSize="20" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <Label Content="OD"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
               FontSize="20" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <Label Content="Length"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
               FontSize="20" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <Button Name="bttnSave"
                Content="Save"
                Margin="2,14,2,2" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                Margin="10,20,25,0">
        <ComboBox Name="cmbDesc"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                  FontSize="23" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <ComboBox Name="cmbOd"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                  FontSize="23" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <TextBox Text="Length"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                 FontSize="25"
                 MaxLength="10" />

        <Label Content="" />

        <Button Name="bttnCancel"
                Content="Cancel"
                Click="bttnCancel_Click"
                Margin="2,14,2,2" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">

        <UserControls:Keypad />
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Now, I do have a default button style, who's code is:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="16px" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                 MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF5EFEF"
                              Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA09C9C"
                              Offset="0.808" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA09C9C"
                              Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF5EFEF"
                              Offset="0.192" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Padding="4,2"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        CornerRadius="7"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Name="contentShadow"
                                          Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1.0"
                                                    Y="1.0" />
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Name="content" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="#FFFDFDFD" />
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Red"
                                                  Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Red"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black"
                                                  Offset="0.573" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black"
                                                  Offset="0.402" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="content"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My question is, why are the buttons reverting to the default setting, when I'm hardcoding height/width values in the user control itself? How can I fix it so that it doesn't do that?

Comment: Do you have any styles that are implicitly overriding `Button` styles in your window template or any of it's resources? It doesn't look like the buttons are different widths which I'd expect from auto width layout based on content. I'd use a grid for layout to be honest though - you want a grid layout so use a grid, dockpanel and stackpanel are not really designed for this type of layout

Comment: I'd also make it grid based for the reason that it will scale automatically if you need to resize it - you can just set the grid width to the total width. As long as you specify * widths for all columns and rows everything will stay in proportion, and since it's a usercontrol you can just style the whole thing with 1 style (width = x, height = y)

Comment: fyi - i just ran your XAML and the button sizes stay the same (except for del)...

Comment: I've just reproduced weird behaviour - I'll post a screenshot in my answer. Use the grid based layout - it will save headache!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a `Grid` based layout:

I'd imagine `DockPanel` and the `StackPanel` instances are doing some weird stuff - and to be honest if you want a uniform grid such as a keypad, it's the way to go

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">1</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">2</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">3</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">Ent</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">4</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">5</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">6</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">7</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">8</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">9</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">0</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">.</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Del</Button>
</Grid>
```

It will also scale perfectly no matter how big or small you want to make it - if needs be you can do some template bindings to set properties such as the button margins etc. via the usercontrol properties

I don't really ever use `DockPanel` if I can help it - I don't think it's the most intuitive of controls

Edit: I added your calc layout and the one above side by side in a 400 x 400 area - this is the result

[image: Don't use dock for grid based layouts!]

(ignore the 1 button on the grid layout, I explicitly set the width to 150 while I was testing styles and forgot to set it back! If you remove the explicit width it scales perfectly like the other buttons)

Comment: I changed it to your grid layout, but I still get the same look as before when I add the control to my window. And when I run it, it looks extremely small. But I'm probably doing something stupid. :(

Comment: Make sure you don't put it in a `Stackpanel` - they will automatically shrink to the LEAST size possible to accommodate the content. If you do, then you must give the control an absolute size so that the stackpanel knows how big it should be. My advice is that if you want a scalable UI, stay away from `Stackpanel` unless you don't care about scaling for a particular part of the UI. i.e. don't put the keypad in a stackpanel - make your UI out of a grid which is 2 x 2 wide or a 2 x 1 grid with nested grids for the other parts

Comment: Worst case, drop the project somewhere (or at least that UC and a test page) and I'd be happy to take a look

Answer (score -2):

You have don't have your LastChildFill property set to False on your top DockPanel. This is the reason "Ent" is changing size and moving your screen.

You also have the HorizontalAlignment on "Del" set to stretch. Try setting that to Left, but might be moot with the LastChildFill correction.

The overall resizing is do to HorizontalAlignment set to Stretch set that to Left.

Comment: If I change it for that button, then that button doesn't fill the way I want it to. I want it under the last column of numbers and under the `Ent` button. Without the stretch, it only appears under the 9. Also, this doesn't change all the buttons to being the size that they should be, which is the size they are in the User Control window.

Comment: I understand that, but have you tried <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> on your top DockPanel? Just skip what I said about the "Del" button, I said the point might be moot.

Comment: I've changed the `LastChildFill` to false, and still have the same issues.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but the you tried the DockPanel that calls 'code' <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">

        <UserControls:Keypad />
    </StackPanel>'code'?